# Make a table using JTable in Java

Tags: java

I want to create table in my form (Jpanel) as shown in pic. I am not getting how to make this same table. I took picture from excel but I want same table in swing form in Java.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write all the code for you?

Comment: unable to add screenshot of the table. How to add screenshot?

Comment: Not full code but idea to make a table,I searched a lot but dint get how to make table without database. As i want to fill this cells dynamically

Comment: Images can be uploaded at imgur.com, but this is still to broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Closing Time (msec)     Triping Time (msec)     Close Open Time (msec)
```

Phase   R   Y   B   N   R   Y   B   N   R   Y   B   N
Time
No. of bounces
A
B
C
D
E
F
G

Comment: unable to add image of table so paste it here . Below each Closing time, tripping time CloseOpen time need to make 4 columns R,Y,B,N. And for first column there is blank space and below this Phase,Tme,No.Of Bounces ,A,B.....Will come.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with TableLayput and fill it with labels.

Comment: Actually I want table like cells in excel. Is there any way to paste cell from excel to Jtable